# Why while loop keep asking to define a variable even if it's already defined?

Tags: python, visual-studio, while-loop

I'm practicing loops in VsCode and watching basic tutorials. I decided to run a very simple code that looks like this

```
x = 1
while x <= 100:
    print(x)
    x = x + 1
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

According to all tutorials I saw it should work. But it doesn't. What could be the problem here?

========================================================================

Comment: please add the language you are asking about as a tag

Comment: i think its python

Comment: Not reproduceable: https://www.online-python.com/wrKxEqVR8C

Comment: Non-reproducible.   Should be something else ...

Comment: So yes thank you. It's kinda started to work again but this problem randomly appears and restarting an application not always helps.